# Деревья в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, дерево

```
.386

;шаблон структуры
Node    struc
namex   db 4 dup(0ffh)
field1  dw 2 dup (0)
Node    ENDS

;логический сегмент
Data1    segment use16
I_struc     db ?
A0 Node <>
A1 Node 2 dup (<>)
A2 Node 4 dup (<>)
A3 Node 8 dup (<>)
adress dw begin2, code2
Data1 ends
```

необходимо создать дерево, где в 2-х элементный массив поля field1 
структуры A0 записывается смещение в сегменте 2-х структур с массива структур 
A1. В 2-х элементный массив поля field1 структуры A1[0] заносим смещение в 
сегменте структур A2[0] та A2[1] и т.д. При написании программы для индексации 
массивов структур использовать байт за адресом I_struc.

```
code1 segment use16
    assume cs:code1, es:Data1
begin:
mov ax, Data1
mov es, ax
mov si, 0;
mov di, 0
mov bx, 0
lea bx, A2[0]
    Loop_Begin:
        mov A0[di].field1[0],bx
        add bx, type A2
        mov A0[di].field1[2],bx
        jle Loop_Begin
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чем состоит ? И filed1[2] быть не может, у нас два элемента с нуля: 0 и 1, под номером 2 это уже третий элемент.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что я попросту не понимаю как сделать это задание, и да, на счет filed1[2] вы абсолютно правы, спасибо.

Comment: Я думаю, что сделал бы функцию, которая принимает 3 параметра (скажем в si, di, cx): указатель на верхний массив, указатель на следующий за ним и количество элементов в верхнем. функция в цикле заполняет field N-ного элемента в первом массиве смещениями N*2 и N*2+1 элементов второго массива. После чего вызвал бы ее 3 раза A0,A1,1; A1,A2,2; A2;A3,4

Comment: Правда в упор не понимаю условие задачи про l_struc.

Comment: Я думаю достаточно будет создать 3 цикла, а вот на условие про l_struc я думаю можно "подзабить"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не могу понять условие "При написании программы для индексации массивов структур использовать байт за адресом I_struc". Система адресации x86 не позволяет использовать однобайтные операнды из памяти для адресации чего либо. А перегружать байт из памяти в регистр, увеличивать на 1 и сохранять обратно в память и все ради того что бы потом его еще умножать на размер структуры и добираться по нему до элемента массива, это явный перебор. Для перехода к следующему элементу гораздо проще просто смещать указатель в регистре на размер структуры.

Вот, с моей точки зрения, оптимальный алгоритм заполнения такого дерева. Все операции с памятью и использование констант внутри циклов сведены к минимуму.

```
        mov  ax, Data1
        mov  ds, ax
        push offset A3       ; Сохраняем адреса уровеней дерева на будущее, в обратном порядке (т.к. стек)
        push offset A2
        push offset A1
        mov  ax, type Node   ; AX - размер структуры, для быстрого использования
        mov  dh, 1           ; DH - количество элементов на текущем уровне дерева
        mov  di, offset A0   ; DI - Адрес второго уровня дерева, в начале цикла он станет первым уровнем (SI)
        mov  cx, 3           ; CX - Количество оставшихся уровней дерева
LevelUP:                     ; Начало цикла по уровням дерева
        mov  si, di          ; SI - Указатель на текущий элемент первого уровня (прошлый второй уровень)
        pop  di              ; Загружаем из стека новый адрес второго уровня
        mov  bx, di          ; BX - смещение текущего элемента второго уровня
        mov  dl, dh          ; DL - оставшееся количество не обработанных элементов в первого уровня
NextNode:                    ; Цикл по элементам первого уровня
        mov  [si].Node.field1[0], bx
        add  bx, ax          ; Смещаем указатель на следующий элемент второго уровня
        mov  [si].Node.field1[1], bx
        add  bx, ax
        add  si, ax          ; Смещаем указатель на следующий элемент первого уровня
        dec  dl
        jnz  NextNode
        shl  dh, 1           ; На следующем уровне в 2 раза больше элементов
        loop LevelUP
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло. И простите, что долго не благодарил, замотался.

Comment: Понял, еще раз спасибо :)